# Achieve pixel perfect on Canvas?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas

I want to make exact 1-pixel thick line without distortions. (means not appeared as 2-pixel lines or 1.5-pixel lines, etc) Because it seems like the Canvas just can't stand Pixel Perfect at times.

Answer (score 1):

It is also depends on CanvasScaler setting, make sure that screen/canvas output is exactly at scale 1x.

- Confirm that canvas final scale is all 1x
- Also confirm that your displaying game window has 1x scale so that 1 pixel show up nicely too!

[image]
(View full unscaled image in another window if sprite in above image appear jagged)

For canvas scaler setting, if you use it in other mode such as "Scale with screen size", and its reference resolution did not match current game window, it will result in non 1x scaling.

[image]

If scale is non uniform, jagged or blurry line will start to appear on canvas.
Notice the middle sword sprite.

Canvas' pixel perfect tick box helped nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, sorry. Canvases try to respect screen pixels when scaling with PixelPerfect set to true.

The solution was pretty easy - just setting PixelPerfect to false. I got so used to set it to true (because of the UI style I was going for before) that I didn't even consider turning it off. I guess that's mainly due to its name - Pixel Perfect.

xD